# Configuration issue in HermesJMS - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for BeanSupport class

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, activemq-artemis, hermes-jms

I am trying to test a message using HermesJMS. I am getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the `BeanSupport` class. What could be the issue?

I have configured the required jars under specific path and configured the same in hermes-config.xml within the tag `</classpathGroup>`.
The `org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.uri.BeanSupport` is present in `artemis-commons-2.0.0.jar` which is already included in classpathGroup which I am able to view under Options->Configuration->Providers in HermesJMS.
I have included all the required jars and configured the same.
Few blogs suggested that the version of jar might be the cause of the issue. I tried all versions of artemis-commons jar yet, I am getting the same error.
Kindly suggest your views on the issue.

The complete stack of the error message :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.uri.BeanSupport
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.uri.schema.serverLocator.AbstractServerLocatorSchema.newConnectionOptions(AbstractServerLocatorSchema.java:29)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.uri.schema.serverLocator.TCPServerLocatorSchema.internalNewObject(TCPServerLocatorSchema.java:42)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.uri.schema.serverLocator.TCPServerLocatorSchema.internalNewObject(TCPServerLocatorSchema.java:33)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.uri.URISchema.newObject(URISchema.java:86)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.uri.URISchema.newObject(URISchema.java:30)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.uri.URIFactory.newObject(URIFactory.java:59)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.newLocator(ServerLocatorImpl.java:411)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:209)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:202)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.invokeConstructor(SerializableClass.java:340)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callNoArgConstructor(SerializableClass.java:292)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1408)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteClientTransport.lookup(RemoteClientTransport.java:243)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:190)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:222)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.performWithRetry(RemoteContext.java:100)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:188)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.store.RelativeFederatingContext.lookupNative(RelativeFederatingContext.java:58)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:66)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at hermes.JNDIConnectionFactory.createConnection(JNDIConnectionFactory.java:105)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:126)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:92)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.reconnect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:81)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.connect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:91)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getConnection(ConnectionSharedManager.java:104)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getObject(ConnectionSharedManager.java:142)
at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.connect(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:190)
at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.getSession(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:570)
at hermes.impl.jms.AbstractSessionManager.getDestination(AbstractSessionManager.java:460)
at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.getDestination(DefaultHermesImpl.java:367)
at hermes.browser.tasks.BrowseDestinationTask.invoke(BrowseDestinationTask.java:141)
at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I'd try the `artemis-jms-client-all-<version>.jar` from the `lib/client` directory of the latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis. That should be the only jar you need aside from the Wildfly JNDI jar(s).

Comment: I read through few blogs and found that the error is due to version mismatch. with activemq-5.3-all jars i am able to resolve this issue. But now, i am getting another issue while trying to send message to queue. It only shows connecting.. and stops with an unexpected error. Any clue about this error ?

Comment: Without more details about the error it's impossible to provide additional help. I recommend you officially answer this question, mark it as answered, and create a new question about your new problem.